# How to find unique rows for a composite key within a day

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I have a table which contains the following values. t1 is considered as day1 with hour values separated by hyphen. I would like to consolidate unique pairs (i.e. p<1..n>, c<1..n> for a day), based on the last occurrence in a day.

```
id1, p1, c1, t1-1
id2, p1, c1, t1-2
id3, p2, c2, t1-2
id4, p3, c3, t1-3
id5, p1, c1, t1-4
id6, p2, c2, t1-4
id7, p1, c3, t1-4
id8, p2, c2, t1-5
id9, p2, c3, t1-5
id10, p2, c4, t1-5
id11, p2, c3, t1-6
id12, p1, c1, t2-1
id13, p1, c2, t2-1
id14, p2, c2, t2-3
id15, p2, c3, t2-3
id16, p1, c1, t2-4
```

The output should be

```
id5, p1, c1, t1-4
id8, p2, c2, t1-5
id4, p3, c3, t1-3
id7, p1, c3, t1-4
id11, p2, c3, t1-6
id10, p2, c4, t1-5 
id16, p1, c1, t2-4
id13, p1, c2, t2-1
id14, p2, c2, t2-3
id15, p2, c3, t2-3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it

```
SELECT id, p, c, t
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, p, c, t
    FROM table1
   ORDER BY t DESC
) q
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(t, '-', 1), p, c
```

Output:

```
|   ID |  P |  C |    T |
|------|----|----|------|
|  id5 | p1 | c1 | t1-4 |
|  id7 | p1 | c3 | t1-4 |
|  id8 | p2 | c2 | t1-5 |
| id11 | p2 | c3 | t1-6 |
| id10 | p2 | c4 | t1-5 |
|  id4 | p3 | c3 | t1-3 |
| id16 | p1 | c1 | t2-4 |
| id13 | p1 | c2 | t2-1 |
| id14 | p2 | c2 | t2-3 |
| id15 | p2 | c3 | t2-3 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3095e/8)** demo

---

**UPDATE:** In Hive you can leverage [analytic functions](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.0.2/ds_Hive/language_manual/ptf-window.html), specifically `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT id, p, c, t
 FROM
(
 SELECT id, p, c, t,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTR(t, 1, INSTR(t, '-') - 1), p, c ORDER BY t DESC) rnum
 FROM table1
) q
 WHERE rnum = 1
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80f86/2)** demo. *It's for Oracle but should work in Hive as is.*

Comment: Thanks @peterm. It's working properly in SQL. How to do the above expected output using Hive?

Comment: @Brisi You're welcome. You should've mentioned Hive in the first place. It's not just some tiny detail. It requires a completely different answer. Anyway see updated answer for a solution.

Comment: Thanku So much!! @peterm.

Comment: I tried this in hive console. Got error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424854/failed-parse-error-line-719-mismatched-input-expecting-from-in-from-claus