# FAILED: Parse Error: line 7:19 mismatched input '(' expecting FROM in from clause

Tags: hadoop, hive

input: table1

```
id1, p1, c1, t1-1
id2, p1, c1, t1-2
id3, p2, c2, t1-2
id4, p3, c3, t1-3
id5, p1, c1, t1-4
id6, p2, c2, t1-4
id7, p1, c3, t1-4
id8, p2, c2, t1-5
id9, p2, c3, t1-5
id10, p2, c4, t1-5
id11, p2, c3, t1-6
id12, p1, c1, t2-1
id13, p1, c2, t2-1
id14, p2, c2, t2-3
id15, p2, c3, t2-3
id16, p1, c1, t2-4
```

The output should be

```
id5, p1, c1, t1-4
id8, p2, c2, t1-5
id4, p3, c3, t1-3
id7, p1, c3, t1-4
id11, p2, c3, t1-6
id10, p2, c4, t1-5 
id16, p1, c1, t2-4
id13, p1, c2, t2-1
id14, p2, c2, t2-3
id15, p2, c3, t2-3
```

Hive query:

```
SET mapred.reduce.tasks=1;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table1(
id string,
t string,
p string,
c string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION 's3://input/';

ALTER TABLE table1 RECOVER PARTITIONS;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table2 (
id string,
t string,
p string,
c string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://output/';
```

Error:

```
hive> 
    >    
    > INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table2
    > SELECT id, p, c, t
    >  FROM
    > (
    >  SELECT id, p, c, t,
    >  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTR(t, 1, INSTR(t, '-') - 1), p, c ORDER BY t DESC) rnum
    >  FROM table1
    > ) q
    >  WHERE rnum = 1
    > ;
FAILED: Parse Error: line 7:19 mismatched input '(' expecting FROM in from clause
```

how to solve this?

Comment: Does `SELECT` work on its own?

Comment: hive> SELECT id, p, c, t,
    >  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTR(t, 1, INSTR(t, '-') - 1), p, c ORDER BY t DESC) rnum
    >  FROM table1;
FAILED: Parse Error: line 2:19 mismatched input '(' expecting FROM in from clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.p, t1.c, t1.time_stamp,
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
( SELECT p, c, Max(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp)) as max_epoch 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY p, c) temp 
WHERE t1.p = temp.p AND t1.c = temp.c AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.time_stamp) = max_epoch ;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the rnum alias (which seems to contradict the LanguageManual syntax) what happens?